# SQL Anywhere : how to get transaction begin timestamp?

Tags: powershell, sqlanywhere

I would like to get the transaction begin timestamp with SQL Anywhere 17.

Below a sample script in Powershell:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName ("Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.5, Version=17.0.8.40434, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f222fc4333e0d400")
$connectionString = "DSN=My_Source;DBN=My_Database;UID=My_User;PWD=My_Password;"
$conn = New-Object Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection($connectionString)
$conn.Open()

$cmd = New-Object Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SACommand('SELECT NOW()', $conn)
$cmd.Transaction = $conn.BeginTransaction([System.Data.IsolationLevel]'ReadCommitted')
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

0..1 | % {
    Start-Sleep $_
    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
    $dt.Clear()
    $dt.Load($reader)
    Write-Host $dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]
}

$cmd.Transaction.Rollback()
$cmd.Dispose()
$conn.Close()
```

And the output:

> 6/4/2018 11:40:01 AM
>   6/4/2018 11:40:02 AM

As you can see consecutive calls to NOW() function provides an increasing timestamp.
I did try using "SELECT CURRENT TIME" without success as well.

Any advice?

Comment: `0..1 | % {
    Start-Sleep $_
...code continues}` --> This part of your code results in increasing time stamp. That loop is making PowerShell sleep for 0 second and 1 second. So if the current time is `6/4/2018 11:40:01 AM`, then after a sleep of 1 second it is bound to be `6/4/2018 11:40:02 AM`. This is kind of expected behavior, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is on purpose: the aim here is to show that NOW() provides the effective current time, whereas in a other RDBMS (e.g. Postgresql) calls to NOW() always provides the transaction begin time.

Comment: My guess is that the answer you'll find is, "That's not how SQL Anywhere transactions work."  I'm basing that on that also not being how SQL Server works.  Since (AFAIK) they share a common T-SQL ancestry, I would imagine that they have similar enough transaction models.  If you need a fixed date and time, either pass it from your application or save it in a variable or temp table server side.  See also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170723/where-can-i-get-sql-server-transaction-begin-time-from